# How can I search in pivot table if using custom filter in yajra-laravel-datatable package (laravel 5.1)

Tags: laravel-5.1

## Schema

**Utility_provider_plan**

```
id, plan_name, etc.
```

**Energy_provider_plan**

```
id, name, etc.
```

**Energy_plan_utility_plans (pivot table)**

```
id, energy_provider_plan_id, utility_provider_plan_id
```

So, I want to filter all result with 'utility_provider_plan_id' column (pivot table).

Here is my code by using yajra-laravel-datatable,

```
return Datatables::of($energyProviderPlans)
->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
    if ($request->has('utility_provider_plan_id')) {
        return $query->utility_provider_plan->where('energy_plan_utility_plans.utility_provider_plan_id', '=', 1);
    }
})
->make(true);
```